# Difference between integrand's variable and variable in integration's limits

Tags: integration, infinitesimals

If a function $G(x)$ is defined by
$$G(x)=\int_a^xf(t)dt$$
Then by the [Fundamental Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part) I can see that $G(x)$ is an antiderivative of $f(x)$ and thus
$$G'(x)=f(x)=\frac{dG(x)}{dx}$$
My confusion starts when I look at the integrand $f(t)$ and its variable $t$. The integrand $f(t)$ must have an antiderivative $F(t)$ as well according to:
$$f(t)=\frac{dF(t)}{dt}$$
The $G$ and $F$ are both antiderivatives of $f$ and therefore must [differ by a constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Proof_of_the_corollary) $c$ at most, which cancels out if you take $dF$ and $dG$, leading to $dF=dG$. Furthermore, if the variables $t$ and $x$ take on the same value $a$ then this would give
$$dG(a)=dF(a)$$
$$f(x=a)=f(t=a)$$
$$\frac{dG(x=a)}{dx}=\frac{dF(t=a)}{dt}$$
The last equation surprises me because I considered the numerators to be equal ($t$ takes on the same value as $x$) but I'm not sure if the intervals $dt$ and $dx$ in the denominators are equal for this equation to be valid. These infinitesimals have different meanings according to the integral so they might not be equal.

If $dt \neq dx$, can someone pinpoint where exactly I went wrong in this reasoning?

Comment: $dx$ and $dt$ are not isolated quantities in Leibniz Notation

Comment: Skip Leibniz notation and rewrite your question using only the prime notation for derivatives. What then becomes of your question?

Comment: [The career of an MSE user consists of reading questions  about $dx$ with ever increasing levels of sophistication](https://www.quora.com/Sidney-Coleman-once-said-%E2%80%9CThe-career-of-a-young-theoretical-physicist-consists-of-treating-the-harmonic-oscillator-in-ever-increasing-levels-of-abstraction-%E2%80%9D-Can-someone-please-put-this-into-perspective-ideally-with-examples).

Comment: @rumathe Can you please elaborate more on this? Do they have a certain relation or do you mean something else?

TedShifrin Do you mean as a limit of $$\frac{F(x+\Delta x)-F(x)}{\Delta x}$$?

Answer (score 0):

The definition of derivative is
$$
F'(a):= \lim_{x \to a} \frac{F(x)-F(a)}{x-a}=\frac{dF}{dx}
$$
Changing $t$ with $x$ in the limit does not change the value of the limit. In other words
$$
\frac{dF}{dt}(t=a):=\lim_{t \to a} \frac{F(t)-F(a)}{t-a}=\lim_{x \to a} \frac{F(x)-F(a)}{x-a}=\frac{dF}{dx}(x=a)
$$
You are basically changing the name of the variable, but actually the name that you give to a variable of a function tell you nothing about the function itself

Comment: Thanks but doesn't the integral show that $x$ has a different meaning than $t$? If it's just a name change as you say, shouldn't this mean that a $dx$ in the limits of the integral is equal to $dt$ which the integrand is integrated over?

Comment: @Phy The variable of integration is what is called a dummy variable. The definition of Riemann integral along an interval is defined (see e.g. [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannIntegral.html)) as $$\int_a^x f(t) dt:= \lim_{|\Delta t_i | \to 0} \sum_{k=1}^n f(t^*_i) \Delta t^i$$ where $\Delta t_i=t_{i+1}-t_i$  $t^*_i \in [t_i, t_{i+1}]$ and $|\Delta t_i |$ is the mesh size of a partition of $[a,x]$. So you can again change the name of the variable (you shouldn't call it $x$ because it is ambiguous, but you technically can do it)

Comment: The point is $\frac{dG}{dx}$ is not a fraction and the $dt$ in the integral is not a quantity. They are notations

Comment: I have difficulty with the term dummy variable in my problem. In the end, doesn't $dt$ have a certain size which can be compared to other infinitesimals? Or is the size of $dt$ actually not determined?

Comment: @Phy read my other comment. $dt$ in the Riemann integral is a notation. Not a quantity. It does not have a size or a value. It is part of the symbol of integral.

Comment: OT the term dummy variable refers to a variable that disappears at the end of a calculation. An example is the index in a summatory. As it does not appear in the final result you can change its name without changing the value of your quantity. *e.g* 
$$ \sum_{i=0}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\sum_{j=0}^n j $$ I changed the name of the dummy variable $i$ with $j$, but the result stays the same. It is the same thing with $t$ in the integral

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanations. I have a feeling physics treat infinitesimals quite differently. Your approach makes me see equations like $f(x)dx=dG$ not having any quantity whatsoever as opposed to similar equations with infinitesimal _physical_ units.

Comment: @Phy There are context in which $dx$ has a meaning on its own, (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form) ), but not in the Riemann integral. $\quad$ Even in physics *e.g* the [work equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_(physics)) the extreme of integration are those who can have physical unit (in the case of the work equation the integral is performed along a path (the displacement). The path has dimension of a length)

Comment: Thanks. I have 1 very last question; I am able to clearly explain the Substitution rule in integrals by dividing an area under a curve into bars with widths of infinitesimal quantities and how to express their areas in terms of other infinitesimal widths. It makes me think, is it _always_ wrong to see infinitesimals as actual quantities even though that approach sometimes makes sense?

Comment: @Phy If you look at the definition of the integral above you will see that is a limit for the mesh size of a partition that goes to zero. The quantity $\Delta t^i$ can be intuitevly seen as an "infinitesimal widths". But I will stress that that quantity is not $dx$.

Comment: Sorry but I noticed my question is better asked when writing it as Riemann summation instead. Suppose the following sum with 2 limits.
$$\lim_{|\Delta x| \to 0}\bigg(\lim_{|\Delta t_i | \to 0} \sum_{k=1}^{n=\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t_i}} f(t^*_i) \Delta t_i\bigg)$$
Thus, let the limits of both the upper limit $\Delta x$ and $\Delta t_i$ go to $0$.
Does $\Delta x$ in this case approach $0$ to the same extent as $\Delta t_i$ does such that they are equal?

Comment: @Phy That sum makes no sense. $\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t_i}$ does not need to be an integer

Comment: You mean it makes no sense _because_ $\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t_i}$ may not be an integer?

Comment: @phy What you have written is not the Riemann sum, neither is well defined. $n$ is the number of subinterval of the partition of the interval $[a,x]$. Morever there is no reason for which that fraction should be an integer. I suggest you to start by reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral) article

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the problem is "leading to $\mathrm dF=\mathrm dG$". You can't really use $\mathrm d$ if you don't have varying quantities to apply them to. Something like "$\mathrm dF$" rather than $\mathrm d\left(F(t)\right)$ doesn't really make sense. If the input didn't matter, then you'd get ridiculous claims like "$F(5+s)$ and $G(7+s)$ must differ by a constant because their derivatives (with respect to $s$) are the same function with different inputs."

You *can* say something like "Let $y$ be $F(s)$ and $z$ be $G(s)$. Then $y$ and $z$ differ by a constant, and $\mathrm dy=\mathrm dz=f(s)\,\mathrm ds$." But then the problem disappears because $s$ is basically a dummy variable, and there's nothing wrong with equations like $$\left.\dfrac{\mathrm{d}G\left(x\right)}{\mathrm{d}x}\right|_{x=a}=\left.\dfrac{\mathrm{d}G\left(s\right)}{\mathrm{d}s}\right|_{s=a}=\left.\dfrac{\mathrm{d}F\left(s\right)}{\mathrm{d}s}\right|_{s=a}=\left.\dfrac{\mathrm{d}F\left(t\right)}{\mathrm{d}t}\right|_{t=a}$$

Comment: My confusion lies more in the fact that $t$ has a different meaning than $x$ according to the integral and yet they give the same derivative. If it's the same as you say, doesn't that mean that an interval $dx$ in the integral's limits is equal to the $dt$ which the integrand is integrated over?

Comment: @Phy Four fellow MSE users are trying to explain to you since 17 hours that the variables have *no* meaning, neither in integration nor in differentiation. (This becomes a little different when we have functions of several variables). Have you thought about Ted Shifrin's comment to OP?